# Reinstalled XAMPP, with deleting htdocs. And old web page shows up at localhost

Tags: xampp

I would like to work on a new project and i have reinstalled XAMPP.

I have tried to make sure i have deleted the whole XAMPP folder, including htdocs (where all the files where). Now when i go to localhost it shows my old project. None of the files from the old project are in 'htdocs' but it still shows up.

I did use htaccess in my old project, this is the only thing i think could be causing this.

I am not sure where it is getting the files from the old project from.

Thanks

Comment: Could this just be because of your browsers cache ?

Comment: Yup. lol... silly me. Thanks!!

Comment: I suggest you either delete this question or create an answer if nobody else does.

Answer (score 0):

The old site was just cached, by clearing my cache, it is now working properly.

Comment: One hint; you should definitely make sure that your webserver configures caching properly. Depending on where you run your site you might run into the problem that a user keeps a cached copy for months and does not get any of the updates you provide. On a test environment this won't matter but in the real world this can give you headaches ...